# Regex to search for matches user by user instead of searching in the entire data

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis

so I have a data dump from where I have to extract information like ifsc code, and id number for every user. This is what the data looks like:

```
00~XXXXXXXXXXXXXX24~
01~John~Doe~Bank~Name~XXXXXXX00~ABCD0123456~
And then some other data which is not required
00~XXXXXXXXXXXXXX23~
01~Jane~Doe~Bank~Name~XXXXXXX00~ABCD0123456~
And then some other data which is not required
```

So from this data, I want to extract the 16 digit code after 00~, 9 digit code after Bank Name and then the IFSC code for every user.

This is what I have done so far using regex:

```
demat = re.findall("00~\d{16}~", content)
micr = re.findall("~\d{9}~", content)
ifsc = re.findall("[A-Z]{4}0[A-Z0-9]{6}", content)
```

However, using this, python is matching all the regular expressions independently (demat, micr and ifsc independently), and returning all of these in lists of different lengths (maybe due to missing data), because of which I am not able to store a user's complete information.

What I want is to store the data in some sort of a list of dictionaries with each dictionary containing data for each user. Is there some way to achieve this? Using some sort of loop or anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please be clear with output format you are aiming to.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all parts in a single regex using `re.finditer`:

```
rx = r'^00~(?P<demat>\d{16})~\r?\n\d+(?:~[^~]*){4}~(?P<micr>[^~]*)~(?P<ifsc>[^~]*)~'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for m in re.finditer(rx, f.read(), re.M):
        print(m.groupdict())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fRJBpk/3/). Note that `micr` and `ifsc` data can be empty as `[^~]*` pattern can match an empty string.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `00~` - `00~` string
- `(?P<demat>\d{16})` - 16 digits captured in `demat` group
- `~\r?\n` - `~` and a CRLF or LF line ending
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:~[^~]*){4}` - four occurrences of `~` and zero or more chars other than `~`
- `~` - a `~` char
- `(?P<micr>[^~]*)` - Group "micr": any zero or more chars other than `~`
- `~` -  a `~` char
- `(?P<ifsc>[^~]*)` - Group "ifsc": any zero or more chars other than `~`
- `~` -  a `~` char

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BtVjWy):

```py
import re
file = "00~1234567890123424~\n01~John~Doe~Bank~Name~123456700~ABCD0123456~\nAnd then some other data which is not required\n00~1234567890123423~\n01~Jane~Doe~Bank~Name~123456700~ABCD0123456~\nAnd then some other data which is not required"
rx = r'^00~(?P<demat>\d{16})~\r?\n\d+(?:~[^~]*){4}~(?P<micr>[^~]*)~(?P<ifsc>[^~]*)~'
for m in re.finditer(rx, file, re.M):
    print(m.groupdict())\
```

Output:

```
{'demat': '1234567890123424', 'micr': '123456700', 'ifsc': 'ABCD0123456'}
{'demat': '1234567890123423', 'micr': '123456700', 'ifsc': 'ABCD0123456'}
```